# xmlhttprequest getting back undefined error or on return data

Tags: javascript, api, xmlhttprequest

I'm having a bit of a problem with the `XMLHttpRequest`. I'm setting up the object the way that I've been led to believe it should be done, but I'm not getting any data back in the response property it's giving always undefined.

```js
function getApi() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
  //xhr.withCredentials = true;
  xhr.responseType = "text/html";
  // xhr.overrideMimeType("application/text");
  xhr.onload = function () {
    return xhr.responseText;
  };

  xhr.send();
}
let status = getApi();
alert(status);
```

Comment: It is because your ``alert`` is executing before the data is fetched from the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) instead:

```js
function getApi() {
  const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
  
  return fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => data)
    .catch(e => e);
}

getApi().then(data => alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)));
```